# connectedhomeip source scripts/bootstrap.sh fails for pw-package

Tags: python, python-3.x

building connectedhomeip (MATTER) using instruction on github on ubuntu 20
failure occurs when running the either of the cmd

> source scripts/bootstrap.sh
> or
> source scripts/activate.sh

using python 3.8 or 3.9

please help

```
    
    Downloading and installing packages into local source directory:
    
      Setting up CIPD package manager...done (4.2s)
      Setting up Python environment.....[-]
    ninja: Entering directory `/home/csir/connectedhomeip/.environment/gn_out'
    [1/248] python3 ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_build/py/pw_build/python_runner.py --gn-root ../../ --current-path ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py --default-toolchain=//build/toolchain/linux:linux_x64_gcc --current-toolchain=//third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_build/python_toolchain:python --touch python/gen/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py/py._run_pip_install.pw_pystamp --capture-output --module pip -- install --no-build-isolation --constraint ../../scripts/constraints.txt --editable ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py
    FAILED: python/gen/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py/py._run_pip_install.pw_pystamp 
    python3 ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_build/py/pw_build/python_runner.py --gn-root ../../ --current-path ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py --default-toolchain=//build/toolchain/linux:linux_x64_gcc --current-toolchain=//third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_build/python_toolchain:python --touch python/gen/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py/py._run_pip_install.pw_pystamp --capture-output --module pip -- install --no-build-isolation --constraint ../../scripts/constraints.txt --editable ../../third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py
    Obtaining file:///home/csir/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_presubmit/py
      Checking if build backend supports build_editable: started
      Checking if build backend supports build_editable: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
    Collecting yapf==0.31.0
      Using cached yapf-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (185 kB)
    Collecting scan-build==2.0.19
      Using cached scan-build-2.0.19.tar.gz (46 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pw-package (from pw-presubmit) (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pw-package
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    ['ninja', '-C', '/home/csir/connectedhomeip/.environment/gn_out', '-v', ':python_packages.install']
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/csir/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/virtualenv_setup/install.py", line 286, in install_packages
        subprocess.check_call(ninja_cmd, stdout=outs, stderr=outs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-C', '/home/csir/connectedhomeip/.environment/gn_out', '-v', ':python_packages.install']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/env_setup.py", line 715, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/env_setup.py", line 707, in main
        return EnvSetup(**vars(parse())).setup()
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/env_setup.py", line 419, in setup
        result = step(spin)
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/env_setup.py", line 538, in virtualenv
        if not virtualenv_setup.install(
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/virtualenv_setup/install.py", line 301, in install
        install_packages(gn_target)
      File "/home/rinel/connectedhomeip/third_party/pigweed/repo/pw_env_setup/py/pw_env_setup/virtualenv_setup/install.py", line 289, in install_packages
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(err.returncode, err.cmd,
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-C', '/home/csir/connectedhomeip/.environment/gn_out', '-v', ':python_packages.install']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fixed it by cloning "connectedhomeip" from github on 15 Feb 2022, now it skips the   pw packages which was causing the issue, the trace is now ->

BOOTSTRAP! Bootstrap may take a few minutes; please be patient. 

Downloading and installing packages into local source directory:

  Setting up CIPD package manager...[[[[[/]
done (20m7.4s)
  Setting up Python environment.....done (4m43.1s)
  Setting up pw packages............skipped (0.1s)
  Setting up Host tools.............done (0.1s)

Comment: git clean -fdx also works in this situation